# Getting a list of installed browsers on the Linux machine

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, browser

I have been looking for a way to get the list of installed browsers on Linux machines (mainly for Ubuntu but would be great if it works for all distributions) I have found a way to do it in Windows from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633190/getting-a-list-of-installed-browsers-on-the-computer).

I am using dotnet 6 (C#)

Answer (score 1):

You can check it in different ways:

1. You can check the `/usr/bin` folder searching for "browser" with a `grep`
2. Or use the following command if you are using ubuntu:
   `dpkg --get-selections | grep browser`

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look in the `.desktop` files in the `/application/` directories, and look for the `Categories=` entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Icon=firefox
StartupWMClass=firefox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
```

You can get the paths by using the environment vars `XDG_DATA_HOME` and `XDG_DATA_DIRS` which is a `:` separated list of directories, and appending `/applications/` on to each of them.

This will detect browsers setup in for most desktop environments as browsers. If you're looking to verify that this is how KDE (for instance) detects browsers, remember to run `sudo update-desktop-database` after you create the `test.desktop` file.